# tcpdump: how to get grepable output?

Tags: linux, networking, tcpdump

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue where I only have tcpdump available on an appliance.
I want to use tcpdump to filter web traffic, and only display traffic containing certain strings.

I do the following:

```
tcpdump -nei eth0 -X | grep "something interesting"
```

The output is a hexview with 16 bytes pr line. I cannot grep this data, as the data is presented on multiple lines.

Is there a way for tcpdump to present the captured data on a single line? This would make it possible to use grep to find interesting packets.

Comment: well, I can't test this right now but if you have multiple lines you could do | tr -d '\n' or grep -C 3 to get some lines before and after

Comment: @barlop, grep -C sort of works, but unreliable, as I never know how many lines up the header will be, and I will not see the lines below the match. The tr command trancates _all_ the output to 1 line, so its a bit too much.

Comment: The following wouldn't be grep, but tcpdump can match strings by hex which is essentially grep without any regex. You can specify an offset. I have this jotted down in a file (done with windump but I that's just a windows version of tcpdump so assume tcpdump) tcpdump -nXr zfile "tcp[32:4] = 0x47455420"

Comment: related: [How to process/pipe TCPDUMPs output in realtime](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/how-to-process-pipe-tcpdumps-output-in-realtime)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For those like you who cannot use `ngrep`, here's how to use `awk` to make the `tcpdump` output of packet contents grepable.

First some sample output as provided by `tcpdump -x`, in order to present the task ahead:

```
$ tcpdump -xr dump.pcap 2>/dev/null
12:04:59.590664 IP 10.17.14.93.51009 > 239.194.1.9.51009: UDP, length 370
        0x0000:  4500 018e 0000 4000 fa11 7625 0a11 0e5d
        0x0010:  efc2 0109 c741 c741 017a 6f28 1120 2020
        0x0020:  3337 3030 3039 3031 3835 3635 3430 3130
...
```

And this is the **copy-and-pastable `awk` script you can pipe the output to**

```
awk '{ if (match($0, /^[0-9]/, _)) { printf (NR == 1 ? "%s " : "\n%s "), $0; fflush() } else { sub(/^\s+0x[0-9a-z]+:\s+/, " "); gsub(" ", ""); printf "%s", $0 } } END { print ""; fflush() }'
```

**in order to get the following, grepable output**

```
12:04:59.590664 IP 10.17.14.93.51009 > 239.194.1.9.51009: UDP, length 370 4500018e00004000fa1176250a...
12:04:59.590798 IP 10.17.14.113.51011 > 239.194.1.11.51011: UDP, length 370 4500018e00004000fa11760f...
...
```

---

Below is a commented version of above script:

```
awk '{
    # if this is a header line
    if (match($0, /^[0-9]/, _)) {
        # print the header, but:

        # except for the first line,
        # we need to insert a newline,
        # as the preceding data lines will
        # have been stripped of theirs

        # we also append a space to
        # separate header info from the
        # data that will get appended
        printf (NR == 1 ? "%s " : "\n%s "), $0
        # enforce line-buffering
        fflush()
    }
    # otherwise it is a data line
    else {
        # remove the data address
        sub(/^\s+0x[0-9a-z]+:\s+/, " ");
        # remove all spaces
        gsub(" ", "");
        # print w/o newline
        printf "%s", $0 
    }
}
END {
    # print final newline, as
    # the preceding data lines will
    # have been stripped of theirs
    print ""
    # enforce line-buffering
    fflush()
}'
```

Answer (score 8):

From the `tcpdump` manpage:

```
-A      Print each packet (minus its link level header) in ASCII.  Handy
        for capturing web pages.
```

Make sure you also use the `-s 0` option to make sure the entire packet is displayed.

Comment: Thanks, but data is still presented at multiply lines - wherever the webpage has newlines in it. I have problem associating the header (and rest of data) with grepped output.

Comment: I just realized why the tool is called awk*ward*

Answer (score 3):

You may want to have a look at `ngrep` command:

`ngrep  -W single  -d eth0  'regex to match'  'port 80'`

Where:

- `-W single` specifies single line formatting
- `regex to match` means to only dump packets containing certain string.
- `'port 80'` is a pcap filter to only sniff packets from or to port 80

Comment: Would like to use ngrep, but there is no such tool - it is an appliance...

Comment: ngrep is awesome. I was searching for hours which host is generating HTTP traffic to my host. With single 
 sudo ngrep "GET .."
found answer in minute.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your output is hex is the `-X` flag. Try:

```
tcpdump -ni eth1 | grep something_interesting
```

You will get dumped readable output right to the cli.

Comment: Yes, but it will not contain the content of the packet.

Answer (score 1):

`tcpdump -nei eth0 -l | grep "something interesting"`

`man 1 tcpdump`: "`-l`     Make stdout line buffered.  Useful if you want to see the data while capturing it."

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the awk script to do what I wanted and ngrep would not work on an Ethernet over USB, so I wrote a small C program to join the lines output by tcpdump so they are grepable. It's at https://gitlab.com/dargaud/TcpDumpJoin